# How to define a set of nodes in abaqus such that the nodes are present inside a 3d block

Tags: python, set, abaqus

I have made a polymer part Abaqus CAE. The size of the polymer box is 40by40by40. I have defined tetrahedral mesh to the part. I need to create a set of nodes such that these nodes are located in a 20by20by20 cube inside 40by40by40 cube(same center point). I tried doing this in CAE but I am unable to define such a node-set. Is it possible to do so in CAE? Can anyone suggest to me how to do this using python scripting?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getByBoundingBox(...)` command to select the nodes in (cubical?) area. Using this command, you can select the entities (geometric or mesh) inside cube bounded by option given (xMin, yMin, zMin, xMax, yMax, zMax). Please read the Abaqus Scripting Reference Guide --> Mesh Commands --> MeshNodeArray object --> getByBoundingBox(...) for clear understanding.

```
mdlName = 'Model-1';  isn = 'Part-1-1'
asm = mdb.models[mdlName].rootAssembly
nodes = asm.instances[isn].nodes.getByBoundingBox(xMin=10,
        yMin=10, zMin=10, xMax=30, yMax=30, zMax=30)
NdSetObj = asm.Set(nodes=nodes, name='nodeSet')
```